# Geometry - Orthocenters and Circumcenter Lengths

Tags: geometry

Let O and H be the circumcenter and orthocenter of triangle ABC, respectively. Let a, b, and c denote the side lengths, and let R denote the circumradius. Find $OH^2$ if $ R = 7 $ and $  a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 29.$

I'm kinda confused on this because if the side lengths are a, b, and c then they should be *about* lengths 2, 3, and 4. So how does R equal 7 then? I'm looking for some help, thanks.

Comment: $OH^2=9R^2-(a^2+b^2+c^2)$. This relation is sometimes referred to as Leibniz's identity.